# Display specific column horizontal based on specific row in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Am looking for a solution to rotate the information that comes from SqlQuery as columns instead of rows using datagridview in vb.net
Eg:-this the table i want to transform from

[image]

Below what i want to display

[image]

Comment: Group by the `Date` field.

Comment: So you want to pivot your data? Didn't say what you're executing you query against, maybe this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15